# SQL Server Express attachment error on other computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I wrote software that needs to connect to a SQL Server database. It works fine on my computer in debug mode or install publish file.

But on another computer, I get a database error. When I check SQL Server Express management, I see the database is not attached to SQL Server. I don't know where is the bug!

This is my connection string :

```
<add name="SamiDbEntities1" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db1\SamiDB1.mdf;Database=SamiDb1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Connect Timeout=30&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: So attach the database using SQL Server Management Studio.  You can do it through a query.  If the database is attached then you do not need to attach in the connection string.  You have a trusted connection so the server will use the login credentials of the user.

Comment: I attach manually in SQL Server Management Studio and use Static connection string it work fine, But i need to do it automatically when i install application.Any idea?

Comment: It is a built in procedure that can be executed like any other SQL Command in a query  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15